# Power Query not recognising data where PowerBI does

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I wish to extract the data from this website:

https://apps.who.int/food-additives-contaminants-jecfa-database/search.aspx?fl=%2b

When I do so in Power query I only get the Kind, Name, Children, Text table.
[image]

However when doing the exact same on PowerBI this recognises the list as desired.

[image]

Can I get Power Query to recognise the data in the same way? Or is there a way to export the Query to Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Power Query in Excel does not have the `Html.Table` function which is used in Power Query in Power BI.

But you can export the data as a csv, then import into Excel.

From the PQ Editor:

- Close and Apply
- Visualize all the columns
- Click in the visualized area
- At the bottom right, you will see an ellipsis

[image]

- Click there and you will be able to select `Export to CSV`

Comment: Hi Thank you! I thought this might be the case. Also, do you know how I might be able to compare the two  generated columns and transform the data such that one column  for example would read (+)-alpha-TOCOPHEROL  and the other (0.15-2 mg/kg bw) etc. Unfortunately I didn't realise this when posting this question.

Comment: @Nick I can think of any number of ways to do this.  Power Query (either in Power BI or Excel), VBA, even Excel formulas.  But I think this warrants a different question where you show what you have, what you want, what you've tried, and where you've run into problems with what you've tried. Before you create your question, it might read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so as to obtain more focused assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a convoluted solution but I have subsequently found how to achieve this using Power Query in Excel. It is possible to navigate the HTML within power query to get to the raw data. Once here the data may not be adjacent to one another but this can be cleaned up easily using power query.

M Code:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://apps.who.int/food-additives-contaminants-jecfa-database/search.aspx?fcc=4")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    Children0 = Data0{0}[Children],
    Children1 = Children0{1}[Children],
    Children2 = Children1{2}[Children],
    Children3 = Children2{2}[Children],
    Children6 = Children3{6}[Children],
    Children4 = Children6{6}[Children],
    Children5 = Children4{1}[Children],
    Children19 = Children5{19}[Children],
    Children7 = Children19{1}[Children],
    #"Expanded Children" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Children7, "Children", {"Kind", "Name", "Children", "Text"}, {"Children.Kind", "Children.Name", "Children.Children", "Children.Text"}),
    #"Expanded Children.Children" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded Children", "Children.Children", {"Kind", "Name", "Children", "Text"}, {"Children.Children.Kind", "Children.Children.Name", "Children.Children.Children", "Children.Children.Text"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Children.Children",{"Kind", "Name", "Children.Kind", "Children.Name", "Children.Children.Kind", "Children.Children.Name", "Children.Children.Children", "Text"}),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Removed Columns",{"Children.Text"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Up", each ([Children.Children.Text] <> null and [Children.Children.Text] <> "Flavouring Agent"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```